# Reorder pandas DataFrame based on repetitive set of integer in index

Tags: pandas, sorting

I have a pandas dataframe contains some columns, I didn't find a way to order rows as follows:

I need to order the dataframe by the field `label` but in sequential order (like groups)

#### Input

```
I category  tags
1   A   #25-74
1   B   #26-170
0   C   #29-106
2   A   #18-109
3   B   #26-86
2   A   #26-108
2   C   #30-125
1   B   #28-145
0   B   #29-93
0   D   #21-102
1   F   #26-108
2   F   #30-125
3   A   #28-145
3   D   #29-93
0   B   #21-102
```

Needed Order:

```
I category  tags
0   C   #29-106
1   B   #25-74
2   F   #18-109
3   C   #26-86
0   B   #29-93
1   D   #26-170
2   B   #26-108
3   B   #28-145
0   C   #21-102
1   D   #28-145
2   A   #30-125
3   A   #29-93
0   B   #21-102
1   A   #26-108
2   C   #30-125
```

---

I have searched for different ways to sort but couldn't find a way to sort **using only pandas**.
I appreciate every help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea with helper column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df['a'] = df.groupby('I').cumcount()

df = df.sort_values(['a','I'])
print (df)
    I category     tags  a
2   0        C  #29-106  0
0   1        A   #25-74  0
3   2        A  #18-109  0
4   3        B   #26-86  0
8   0        B   #29-93  1
1   1        B  #26-170  1
5   2        A  #26-108  1
12  3        A  #28-145  1
9   0        D  #21-102  2
7   1        B  #28-145  2
6   2        C  #30-125  2
13  3        D   #29-93  2
14  0        B  #21-102  3
10  1        F  #26-108  3
11  2        F  #30-125  3
```

Or first sorting by column `|` and then change order with [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) and [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('I')
df = df.iloc[df.groupby('I').cumcount().argsort()]
print (df)
    I category     tags
2   0        C  #29-106
0   1        A   #25-74
3   2        A  #18-109
4   3        B   #26-86
8   0        B   #29-93
1   1        B  #26-170
5   2        A  #26-108
12  3        A  #28-145
9   0        D  #21-102
7   1        B  #28-145
6   2        C  #30-125
13  3        D   #29-93
14  0        B  #21-102
10  1        F  #26-108
11  2        F  #30-125
```